# get_template_part function and add thumbnail on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Added this function in any page:

```
get_template_part('recent', 'posts');
```

And:

```
if(have_posts()){
while(have_posts()){ the_post(); ?>
    <div class="site-content clearfix"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php }
}
```

It's working, show 5 blog post on my page. But it's have only title and publish date. I want add thumbnail images on this post.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like this to The Loop:

```
if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

Your posts will need to have the Featured Image (formerly called the Post Thumbnail) set.

**Edited**

More in-depth code:

```
if( have_posts() ){
    while( have_posts() ){ 
        the_post(); 
        if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
        }
        ?>
        <div class="site-content clearfix"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        <?php 
    }
}
```

Please note, though, that if a post doesn't have a Featured Image set, then `the_post_thumbnail()` won't get called.

#### Reference

- [Post Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)

Comment: It should be in the same general vicinity as the rest of [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). I'll edit my answer for more clarity.